# imbalanced dataset

Tags: classification, auc, unbalanced-classes, boosting

I am working on a classification problem with a highly imbalanced dataset. The ratio background to signal is about 20.

I trained an **xgboost** model. The ROC curve looks perfect and ROC_auc is also almost perfect 0.99.
But the BDT response or probability to be[ a signal for a signal (training and test sets) looks very incorrectly.

[image]

I tried to balance the data by adding weight to the data, but without success. 
Can you give me any advices how to deal with highly imbalanced datasets?

Comment: What is the cost function you train the classifier with?  How do you pick the threshold for the actual classification? What is BDT?

Answer (score 3):

Learning under imbalanced datasets is an active research area in machine learning [1]. Algorithms that have to deal with imbalanced datasets can be categorized into 4 groups: (i) under-sampling, (ii) over-sampling, (iii) combination of over- and under-sampling, and (iv) ensemble learning methods.

[imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) is a Python library that implements some of the aforementioned algorithms, has a simple interface and it is compatible to `scikit-learn`.

[1] http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5128907/

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: @gung I extended my answer